# Count markers along line using turf/Leaflet

Tags: turfjs

I added markers along many lines using turf, now I want to count number of markers on each line and also total of this markers. I tried using **length** but it return undefined. Do you have idea how to do that?

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= (linesPoints-Ecart /2)/Ecart; i++)
    {
       marker = turf.along(pathLine[i], Ecart/2+Ecart*i, 'meters');
       var inside= turf.intersect(marker, poly);
       if(inside)
       {
        geojsonMarker =L.geoJson(marker).addTo(map);
           console.log(marker.length);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call [along()](http://turfjs.org/docs/#along), it just returns one Point. It doesn't return all the points on the line you've added. Have a look at the return value in a debugger or console.log() statement and you'll see what kind of data you actually have--no need for it to be a mystery.

In your code snippet, I think you can get the count of the markers without using any data generated by Turf. Your calling code knows when a marker is being added, right? Just track the count of markers added in your own variable as you go, like...

```
var markerCount = 0; 
for (var i = 0; i <= (linesPoints-Ecart /2)/Ecart; i++)
{
   marker = turf.along(pathLine[i], Ecart/2+Ecart*i, 'meters');
   var inside= turf.intersect(marker, poly);
   if(inside)
   {
      geojsonMarker =L.geoJson(marker).addTo(map);
      console.log(++markerCount);
   }
}
```

This would give you a count of all markers added to one line. If you want a count of all markers added to all lines, just track it yourself. I don't know how your code is laid out beyond your initial example, but imagine the snippet above is put into one function like...

```
function addMarkersToLine(linePoints, ecart) {
   //...same code from above goes in here...
   return markerCount; //Returning number of markers added for just this line.
}
```

And then you have some code elsewhere responsible for adding markers for one or multiple lines...

```
function addTwoLines() {
   var totalMarkerCount = 0;
   totalMarkerCount += addMarkersToLine(...params...);
   totalMarkerCount += addMarkersToLine(...params for a different line...);
}
```

How you track and store the marker counts is up to you and differs depending on your project. But my main point is, track it yourself instead of using Turf to do some kind of analysis or relying on knowledge of how Turf will compose the GeoJson to handle your turf.along() request. In the calling code, you already know when you are adding markers.

Comment: Thank yo for your answer, but this it return the count of markers in each line, in my case I want to get the sum of all this markers

Comment: What value of the markers are you trying to sum? When you say "sum", I think you mean to add a set of values together, but if that is true, then I don't know which value associated with the marker you mean.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear. My purpose is to calculate how many markers are displaying on the map, when I said "sum", I mean to calculate number of all markers. For instance if I have 3 lines and on each line there is 10 markers, I want to get the sum equal to 30 markers.

Comment: As you say, the code above counts the markers in one line. If you want to count all the markers in all the lines, then I think you can just add the line counts together, right? I will add a small code sample to the answer.